# NIO. Multiple client channels listening on same port

Tags: java, nio

Using NIO, how do I register multiple client connections on the same machine to listen on the same port.

I have something like this for the first channel...

```
channel1 = DatagramChannel.open();
channel1.configureBlocking(false);
channel1.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(localPort));
channel1.connect(socketAddress);
SelectionKey key1 = channel1.register(readSelector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
key1.attach(driverHandler1);
```

Now how do I configure channel2 to also listen on the same port since I cant bind() again.

Comment: Only one resource can be bound to one port at a time, even in NIO, afaik.

Comment: @Fildor That is not correct for UDP, or for TCP either if you use a different interface each time.

Comment: @EJP Thanks. Seems I should read into NIO. We're using "the old stuff" still :(

Comment: @Fidor It has nothing to so with NIO whatsoever. These are basic properties of UDP and TCP, available via any API, which you should already know if you are posting comments about it. There's nothing that NIO, or any other API, could do about it even if it wanted to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you bind each channel you must call channelN.socket().setReuseAddress(true), for each N. Then you can bind them all.